# Head element only renders on first page load

Tags: python, html, http, flask

I have a strange issue where with my very first `flask` app, and that is for my `index.html` template, the `head` tag only renders the first time I visit the page. As soon a I do a hard refresh, it doesn't render. My template is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head

<body>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>Python versions:</p>
    {% for ver in example_list %}
        <p>{{ver}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect this has something to do with caching, but not sure. Why does the page load properly the first time, each time. I have do open a new tab though, just visiting the same URL again on the same tab also reveals zero presence of the `head` tag.

For bonus points, why does my `glyphicon` span not render on any page load?

Comment: Are the pages being cached?

Comment: @Vbudo Probably, I don't know how to tell, but if it is caching, why always work on the first load - the cache should only get refreshed on a hard refresh, yet a soft refresh seems to remove the cache and render no `head` tag.